# selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1 Can not find firefox binary in path

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I am just upgrading to selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1 on our Selenium Grid hub and on the nodes.

What I realised is, that the JSON config has slightly changed (https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Grid2).

After changing my configuration accordingly the node is starting fine. However I can not run any tests on firefox because I get the following error:

```
Exception: Cannot find firefox binary in PATH. Make sure firefox is installed.   OS appears to be: VISTA
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0700'
System info: host: 'ebc-vie-selenium-node-01', ip: '10.100.0.157', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
```

The JSON configuration looks like this:

```
"capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "version": "49.0.2",
      "platform": "WINDOWS",
      "firefox_binary": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\ESR\\Firefox_49.0.2\\firefox.exe",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
```

When I set the firefox_binary directly from Java code it works fine (with Gecko Driver)

```
desiredCapabilities.setCapability("firefox_binary", "C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Mozilla Firefox\\\\ESR\\\\Firefox_49.0.2\\\\firefox.exe");
```

Any idea why that is happening respectively how the JSON configuration has changed for version 3.0.1

Comment: try as follows in config file **"firefox_binary": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/ESR/Firefox_49.0.2/firefox.exe",**

Comment: Hi, my config file looks now like this '{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "firefox",
          "version": "49.0.2",
          "platform": "WINDOWS",
    "firefox_binary": "C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/ESR/Firefox_49.0.2/firefox.exe",
          "maxInstances": 5,
    "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },' Still get the error that it can not find firefox binary in path. It works fine when I use only one firefox instance installed in the appropriate directory.

Comment: try only "binary" instead of "firefox_binary" in the config file

Comment: nice tip - but also not working for me. I don't get it why it's not working after upgrading to version 3.0.1 whereas it worked finde with 2.45.0

Comment: ok. try adding to PATH system environment variable. only till "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\ESR\\Firefox_49.0.2" and restart the machine and then try.